# Is it possible to write this generic in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, generics

I have some data types:

```
  type
    TICD10CodeMap = TObjectDictionary<string, TICD10LookupResult>;
    TStringMap = TDictionary<string, string>;
    TFMRecMap = TDictionary<string, TFilemanRecord>;
```

And some instances of them:

```
  var
    FICD10Codes: TICD10CodeMap;
    FPatientTypes: TStringMap;
    FPOVs: TFMRecMap;
    FTreatmentTypes: TStringMap;
    FTypesOfCare: TStringMap;
```

And I had a method that was happily populating them, using their Add methods, until I discovered that my data source could have duplicate keys in it.

Now I could just write code with ContainsKey before each and every Add() and do something, but I thought I would be clever:

```
procedure AddPair<ValType, DictType: TDictionary<string, ValType>>
    (Key: string; Val: ValType;
    Dict: DictType);
begin
  if (Dict as TDictionary<string, ValType>).ContainsKey(Key) then
    AddPair('Copy of ' + Key, Val, Dict)
  else
    Dict.Add(Key, Val);
end;
```

But it seems I am too clever for Delphi. First off, there's that cast in the body of the function definition, which seems like it ought to be unnecessary, then there's the fact that when I try to call `AddPair`, I get compiler errors. The naive `AddPair(s3, s2, FPatientTypes)` gets me both

```
[dcc32 Error] uReverseVistaLookups.pas(116): E2010 Incompatible types: 'ValType' and 'string'
[dcc32 Error] uReverseVistaLookups.pas(116): E2010 Incompatible types: 'DictType' and 'System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary<System.string,System.string>'
```

while the would-be-more-sophisticated `AddPair<string, TStringMap>(s3, s2, FPatientTypes)` complains about

```
[dcc32 Error] uReverseVistaLookups.pas(127): E2515 Type parameter 'ValType' is not compatible with type 'System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary<System.string,System.string>'
```

Is there some incantation that I'm missing, which would make Delphi out of what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: This doesn't appear to need a generic method. You've already instantiated the generic types. Use the type aliases that you declare in the first block of code in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan no, I want to have a single identifier with which I can replace all calls to the Add methods of the assorted containers. I have answered myself, see below.

Comment: So why did you declare those types?

Comment: And I suppose a bigger issue is how you can usefully look anything up after changing all the keys. Sounds like the wrong data structure has been chosen.

Comment: `I could just write code with ContainsKey before each and every Add() ` - reinventing the wheel, why??? Enter http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Generics.Collections.TDictionary.AddOrSetValue :  **AddOrSetValue** _adds a key-value pair to a dictionary even if the key already exists. The key cannot be nil, but the value can. This method checks to see if the key exists in the dictionary, and if it does, it is equivalent to_ `Items[key] := value;`. _Otherwise it is equivalent to_ `Add(key, value);`.

Comment: @Arioch'The This is totally different behaviour.  For reasons that escape logic, OP *wants* to insert duplicate items.  `AddOrSetValue` simply overwrites a previous entry with the same key.  OP wants to keep both copies and seems to want to generate a unique derivative key when key collisions occur.

Comment: @J... aaah... totally overlooked it, sure. But then I guess the TS should add a bit more intelligent approach to avoid "Copy of Copy of Copy of Copy of xxxxx" monsters. He should, I think, check if he already inserts a copy and then insert and increase a counter. `AddPair('AAA', 0, Dict); AddPair('AAA', 1, Dict); AddPair('AAA', 2, Dict); AddPair('Copy of AAA', 3, Dict);`

Comment: Looks like a dictionary is the wrong data structure here if you can have multiple values for one key. Should use a multimap.

Comment: @J...: I don't actually want to insert items with duplicate keys, I just want a terse way of testing whether some TDictionary with an arbitrary ValType already contains the key so I don't try to add it twice. Without explicitly writing ContainKey every single place where I'd be adding a value. This is a situation where I *discovered* that there could be duplicate keys after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D'oh.

There is no need for two type parameters in the generic:

```
procedure AddPair<ValType>(Key: string; Val: ValType;
    Dict: TDictionary<string, ValType>);
```

is easy to write (without the troublesome cast!) and does what it should.

Comment: Personally I would do it as a class helper instead, kind of "adding" new method to the `TDictionary<x,y>` class itself. That if I really need "ignore second value" behavior. Otherwise I would just use readymade stock `TDictionary<x,y>.AddOrSetValue` method

Comment: No, AddPair is a method on the thing that contains the dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

While this seems like an odd way to use a `TDictionary`, an easy way to get what you want is simply to subclass.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
  Generics.Collections, SysUtils;

type
  TCopyKeyMap<TValue> = class(TDictionary<string, TValue>)
    public
      procedure AddWithCopy(const Key: string; const Value: TValue);
  end;
  TStringMap = TCopyKeyMap<string>;

procedure TCopyKeyMap<TValue>.AddWithCopy(const Key: string; const Value: TValue);
begin
  if ContainsKey(Key) then
    AddWithCopy('Copy of ' + Key, Value)
  else
    Add(Key, Value);
end;

var
  sm : TStringMap;
  sp : TPair<string, string>;
begin
  sm := TStringMap.Create;
  try
    sm.AddWithCopy('foo', 'bar');
    sm.AddWithCopy('foo', 'bat');
    sm.AddWithCopy('foo', 'bam');
    for sp in sm do WriteLn(Format('%s : %s', [sp.Key,sp.Value]));
  finally
    sm.Free;
  end;
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: Also I believe while loop would be better than recursion here, though it is a matter of tastes, practically.

Comment: @Arioch'The It's a silly idea to begin with, to be honest.  The practicality of managing a dataset with a bunch of ridiculous quasi-duplicate keys will become a problem long before recursion.